# Making an input text file as a training data set in libsvm

Tags: libsvm

I am working on hydraulic simulation using epanet, and I have got various leaky and normal flow, pressure values of nodes and links.

I want to train these output values using libsvm. I have got the output (hydraulic simulation) in different format.

My question is whether it is possible to add that output as training input to the libsvm.

Comment: if your output values can be stored in `csv`, you can use `csv2libsvm` to convert the format.

Comment: here is the git repo for `csv2libsvm` https://github.com/zygmuntz/phraug/blob/master/csv2libsvm.py

Answer (score 0):

If your output format can be stored in a generic `CSV` format, you can use `csv2libsvm` to convert the data into `libsvm` format.

The git repo can be found here:
https://github.com/zygmuntz/phraug/blob/master/csv2libsvm.py

Note that the tool is written in `python`.