# Load Data for Machine Learning in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataset where I want to perform some supervised task (regression, decision tree). The dataset is here:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+%28German+Credit+Data%29

The data are in plain text file in the format

Data1 Data2 Data3 .....

I checked the Spark Mlib tutorials from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html
and they used data in libSVM format so they used loadLibSVMFile function.

My question is this: now that I don't have this format how can I load the data and pass the labels for the variables. Which method should I use?

I checked MLutil data documentation and no method strike me as the one I need https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLUtils.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829531/making-an-input-text-file-as-a-training-data-set-in-libsvm and http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/doc/converter.html

Comment: I can't do it natively with scala?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416291/how-to-prepare-data-into-a-libsvm-format-from-dataframe

Comment: thnx that is helpful indeed